# how to change head meta data when switch the language in VUE?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, internationalization, nuxt.js

is there anyone ask that question yet ? if yes, please give me the link to read this question, if not, how to do that ?
I want to change the head tittle and description each user switch the language , how can I do that ?? I do love to get some help, I am. a beginner for this :D

i have `gallery.vue`

i am using nuxt js here

and using nuxt-i18n
based vue-i18n

```
<template lang="html">

  <div class="">
    <p> {{ $t('post') }}</p>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  head () {
    return {
      tittle: // how to change tittle here for the spesific languange
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="css">
</style>
```

i want the result like 
when in english the head tittle to be Gallery
and when user switch the italianq , the head will be the Galleria

Answer (score 6):

This maybe a bit late but to help new comers.

As per documentation you may use function to set meta data so with function you access data and computed (including this), check the code:

```
head() {
 return {
  title: this.$t('myTitle'),
  htmlAttrs: {
    lang: this.$i18n.locale,
  },
  meta: [
    {
      hid: 'description',
      name: 'description',
      content: this.$t('myDescription'),
    },
  ],
 }
```

},

source: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/meta-tags-seo#local-settings

Answer (score 1):

Look for vue-meta library. I'm using it for this purposes. In App.vue:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',

  metaInfo () {
    return {
      htmlAttrs: {
        lang: this.$i18n.locale
      },
      ...
    }
  },

  data () {
  ...
}
</script>
```

Comment: i dont have app.vue because i am using nuxt? should  i put it on default.vue ??
 
anyway, the ... should i write it also?

Comment: I have no idea. Meta works with SSR, but read the Meta documentation first.

Comment: how about change the SEO ??

Comment: Nuxt is using vue-meta by default. Just read the Nuxt documentation.

Comment: still looking , and get confused

Comment: they still fix it

Comment: Sorry for that, but I can't help. I'm not using Nuxt.

Comment: i got it ```this.$i18n.messages[this.$i18n.locale].yourPropHere``` for head function

Answer (score 1):

i got it 
just add head function and return the tittle: `this.$i18n.messages[this.$i18n.locale].yourPropHere`